# How to deep copy a page of puppeteer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using `puppeteer` to navigate my website. I want to wait for an api that sometimes gets called and sometimes not. I'm using

```
await page.waitForResponse((response =>response.url().includes(myurl)), { timeout: 1000 });
```

to wait for that api. This works fine when the api gets called, but whenever the api doesn't get called, it crashes and the page isn't same anymore. So, I want to deep copy the page so that I can just check for the api via it's copy and even if that page gets damaged. I will have another that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to copy your page. That's probably not doable very easy and seems like a bit of overkill. Instead, **preventing** the page from **crashing** would be a simpler approach.

Try something like this:

```js
async function waitForApi(url, timeoutMs) {
   try {
       console.log('waiting ', timeoutMs+'ms for special API. url:', url);
       const opts = { timeout: timeoutMs || 1000 };
       await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes(url), opts);
       console.log('Special API was called!.');
       return true;
   } catch(err) {
       console.log('Special Api was appearantly not called. (Or may be failed.. Error:', err);
       return false;
   }
}
 
// example call of waitForApi .. 
const myUrl = '...'
const apiCalled = await waitForApi(myUrl, 1000)

if(apiCalled) {
   // do stuff if you want to..
} else {
   // do stuff if you want to..
}
```

This should now log if the api was called or not and when needed you can handle the cases differently.